# Using action button with R flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

Is it possible to use an action button with R flexdashboard?

for example in the repex below, is it possible to add a button so that the code will run only when the button is displayed?

I can not find documentation on the website https://garrettgman.github.io/rmarkdown/flexdashboard/using.html#html_widgets

and most of the information that are google deals with using action button in a "pure" shiny app not flexdashboard.

````
---
title: "example"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {data-width=100}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
numericInput("n1", "First number", 10)  


```

Column {data-width=900}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}

DT::renderDataTable({
  

x = sample(1:input$n1, size=500, replace=TRUE)
x= as.data.frame(x)

  DT::datatable(x, options = list(
    bPaginate = FALSE
  ))
})


```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can include an `actionButton` just as you use the `numericInput` and then e.g. use the `eventReactive` programming pattern:

````
---
title: "example"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {data-width=100}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
numericInput("n1", "First number", 10)  
actionButton("execute", "Generate data")

```

Column {data-width=900}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
table_data <- eventReactive(input$execute, {
  x = sample(1:input$n1, size=500, replace=TRUE)
  as.data.frame(x)
})


DT::renderDataTable({
  req(table_data())
  
  
  
  DT::datatable(table_data(), options = list(
    bPaginate = FALSE
  ))
})


```
````

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for and it is simple enough to understand and apply to other scenarios.

Comment: Thank you, how does it have to be with a ggplot instead of a datatable?

Comment: Instead of `renderDataTable` you can use `renderPlot` and put the `ggplot` code inside it